# Can Such An Object Be Considered Immutable?

Tags: .net, immutability

I have designed a class containing some information about a given object which will be registered in an SQL Server database. I would like to make this object (deeply) immutable, but I also must assure that it gets registered only once. If this object implements the following pattern, can it still be considered immutable?

```
public class NewClass
{
    private bool registered;

    public string SomeProperty { get; private set; }

    public NewClass Register()
    {
        if (registered)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(/*arguments*/);
        }

        /* Register on DB here... */
        registered = true;
        return new NewClass(somePropertyFromDB);
    }

    public NewClass(string someProperty)
    {
        registered = false;
        SomePropery = someproperty;
    }
}
```

I would say that except for the boolean field `registered` the object is immutable, but this fields leaves me some doubts because it will actually change on the first time the `Register` method is executed... Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this problem and still make the object be immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's definitely *not* immutable. The `registered` value changes over the lifetime of the object.

To make it immutable, you mustn't allow the `registered` field to change over the lifetime of the object - instead, make `Register` return a new object which has a `true` value for `registered`

I'd also remove the private setter for `SomeProperty`, just having a getter and a readonly variable.

So something like this:

```
public class NewClass
{
    private readonly bool registered;
    private readonly string someProperty;

    public bool Registered { get { return registered; } }
    public string SomeProperty { get { return someProperty; } }

    public NewClass Register()
    {
        // Note the change of exception here
        if (registered)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already registered");
        }

        return new NewClass(somePropertyFromDB, true);
    }

    // You may want to have a public constructor with just someProperty
    // which calls this one, which you could make private
    public NewClass(string someProperty, bool registered)
    {
        this.registered = registered.;
        this.someProperty = someproperty;
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Another option would be to have two separate classes, `RegisteredFoo` and `UnregisteredFoo`; that might make it easier to understand code using this class
- There's nothing to stop someone calling `Register` twice, so making this immutable doesn't really help in terms of idempotency. As there's a natural side-effect (talking to the database) it's hard to make this truly functional.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your answer, but the setter for `SomeProperty` is marked as `private`. And as for the solution to the `registered` problem, even that way I can't assure that a user doesn't write `Instance1.Register(); Instance1.Register()`. Both of them will return a new object, but since I am keeping the original reference, I can execute the methods many times.